# how to see the payment has been sent via card in sandbox

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am creating a shopping cart app in android application where there is a feature of payment.

For that i am using paypal android sdk. I am using sandbox account.

When i am sending money through paypal it is showing me that the payment has been sent and in receiver account i can see that receiver received the money as well. But when i am using card for transaction, Application is showing me that payment has been done But it is neither showing me in the receiver account nor in the sender account. Can any one help me in that issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the testing dashboard: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/dashboard/test

It should show you all credit card related notifications. For PayPal transactions, look at the notifications option on the left.